# Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma proof.

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Assume that $f(x)$ is $2π$-periodic and square integrable on $(−π, π)$.

Can someone help me show how following statements are true 
using Bessel's Inequality?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx=0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx=0~.$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $e_n(x)=\cos(nx)$. Then $\{e_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal family of functions in $L^2[-\pi, \pi]$. Hence, for any $f\in L^2[-\pi, \pi]$: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |\langle f, e_n\rangle|^2 \leq ||f||_2$. In particular we must hvae $|\langle f, e_n\rangle| \rightarrow 0$ which is exactly what you want. The proof is the same for the $\sin$ functions.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $e_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(nx)$? (the remaining argument still follows since the normalization constant doesn't depend on $n$)

Comment: You are right, thanks